# How to add new element and take away some old elements from an array of associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this array of associative array in php.

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'Field1' => '0_Val_1',
            'Field2' => '0_Val_2',
            'Time3' => '2014-04-08 10:00:00',
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'Field1' => '1_Val_1',
            'Field2' => '1_Val_2',
            'Time3' => '2014-04-08 11:00:00',
        )
    )
```

I want to take away certain elements and add new elements to each of the associative array inside the array. The output will look like this;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'Field1' => '0_Val_1',
            'Time3' => '2014-04-08 10:00:00',
            'Time4' => '2014-04-08 10:00:01'    
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'Field1' => '1_Val_1',
            'Time3' => '2014-04-08 11:00:00',
            'Time4' => '2014-04-08 10:00:01'
        )
    )
```

`'Field2'` was removed and `'Time4'` was added. `'Time4'` is equal to 1 secs added to `'Time3'`.

How can this be done in php? I am sorry I do not even have some starting code because this array is rather complicated for me.

Comment: What is your current approach?

Comment: Working on it at the moment. Will post some code once there is something worthy to show.

Comment: @user3293156: You `foreach` over your array and operate on each sub-array individually. Removing and adding items to those are basic array operations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The code using foreach is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plain approach will be to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) or loops like:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'Field1' => '0_Val_1',
            'Field2' => '0_Val_2',
            'Time3' => '2014-04-08 10:00:00',
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'Field1' => '1_Val_1',
            'Field2' => '1_Val_2',
            'Time3' => '2014-04-08 11:00:00',
        )
    )
);

$remove = ['Field2']; //which keys to remove
$new    = ['Time4'=>['Time3'=>'+1 second']]; //new Time4 depends of old Time3 with +1second

$result = array_map(function($x) use ($remove, $new)
{
   return array_map(function($y) use ($remove, $new)
   {
      $y = array_diff_key($y, array_flip($remove));
      foreach($new as $key=>$exp)
      {
         $y[$key] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($y[key($exp)].current($exp)));
      }
      return $y;
   }, $x);
}, $data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will need some time to study your code. I didn't know there are so many different types of array functions in php.

Comment: I went to the documentation for array_map(). There is no mention of the keyboard `use`. How does `use` come in?